# VBA - Trapping events on dynamically created Textbox

Tags: vba, excel, events, userform

I am writing a VBA application in Excel. I have a Userform that dynamically builds itself based upon the data contained in one of the worksheets.
All of the code that creates the various comboboxes, textboxes and labels is working.
I created a class module to trap OnChange events for the Comboboxes, and again this works as expected.
Now I have a need to trap OnChange events for some of the textboxes, so I created a new class module modelled on that for the comboboxes to trap the events.

```
Public WithEvents tbx As MSForms.TextBox

Sub SetTextBox(ctl As MSForms.TextBox)
Set tbx = ctl
End Sub

Public Sub tbx_Change()
Dim LblName As String

MsgBox "You clicked on " & tbx.Name, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

The message box is just so that I can confirm it works before I go further.
The problem I'm getting is in the UserForm code module:

```
Dim TBox As TextBox
Dim tbx As c_TextBoxes

'[...]

Set TBox = lbl
Set tbx = New c_TextBoxes
tbx.SetTextBox lbl
pTextBoxes.Add tbx
```

This throws up a type mismatch error at `Set TBox=lbl`. It's the **exact** same code that works fine for the ComboBox, just with the variables given approriate names. I've stared at this for 2 hours.
Anyone got any ideas? Thanks for any pointers.

Edit - Here's the full userform module that I'm having trouble with:

```
Private Sub AddLines(FrameName As String, PageName As String)
Dim Counter As Integer, Column As Integer
Dim obj As Object
Dim CBox As ComboBox
Dim cbx As c_ComboBox
Dim TBox As TextBox
Dim tbx As c_TextBoxes
Dim lbl As Control

Set obj = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(PageName).Controls(FrameName)
If pComboBoxes Is Nothing Then Set pComboBoxes = New Collection
If pTextBoxes Is Nothing Then Set pTextBoxes = New Collection

For Counter = LBound(Vehicles) To UBound(Vehicles)
     For Column = 1 To 8
     Select Case Column
     Case 1
         Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblMachine" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 2
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblFleetNo" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 3
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblRate" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 4
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblUnit" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 5
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "CBDriver" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 6
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblDriverRate" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 7
        Set lbltbx = obj.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TBBookHours" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    Case 8
        Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LblCost" & FrameName & Counter, True)
    End Select
    With lbl
        Select Case Column
        Case 1
            .Left = 1
            .Width = 60
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            .Caption = Vehicles(Counter).VType
        Case 2
            .Left = 65
            .Width = 40
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            .Caption = Vehicles(Counter).VFleetNo
        Case 3
            .Left = 119
            .Width = 50
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            .Caption = Vehicles(Counter).VRate
        Case 4
            .Left = 163
            .Width = 30
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            .Caption = Vehicles(Counter).VUnit
        Case 5
            .Left = 197
            .Width = 130
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            Set CBox = lbl 'WORKS OK
            Call CBDriver_Fill(Counter, CBox)
            Set cbx = New c_ComboBox
            cbx.SetCombobox CBox
            pComboBoxes.Add cbx
        Case 6
            .Left = 331
            .Width = 30
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
        Case 7
            .Left = 365
            .Width = 30
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
            Set TBox = lbl 'Results in Type Mismatch
            Set tbx = New c_TextBoxes
            tbx.SetTextBox TBox
            pTextBoxes.Add tbx
        Case 8
            .Left = 400
            .Width = 30
            .Top = 10 + (Counter) * 20
        End Select
    End With
    Next
Next
obj.ScrollHeight = (Counter * 20) + 20
obj.ScrollBars = 2

End Sub
```

And here's the c_Combobox class module:

```
Public WithEvents cbx As MSForms.ComboBox

Sub SetCombobox(ctl As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set cbx = ctl
End Sub

Public Sub cbx_Change()
Dim LblName As String
Dim LblDriverRate As Control
Dim i As Integer


    'MsgBox "You clicked on " & cbx.Name, vbOKOnly
    LblName = "LblDriverRate" & Right(cbx.Name, Len(cbx.Name) - 8)
    'MsgBox "This is " & LblName, vbOKOnly

    'Set obj = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(PageName).Controls(FrameName)
    Set LblDriverRate = UFBookMachines.Controls(LblName)
    For i = LBound(Drivers) To UBound(Drivers)
        If Drivers(i).Name = cbx.Value Then LblDriverRate.Caption = Drivers(i).Rate
    Next
End Sub
```

And finally, here's the c_TextBoxes class module:

```
Public WithEvents tbx As MSForms.TextBox

Sub SetTextBox(ctl As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set tbx = ctl
End Sub

Public Sub tbx_Change()
Dim LblName As String
    'Does nothing useful yet, message box for testing
    MsgBox "You clicked on " & tbx.Name, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `lbl` defined and what is the type?  Where is this code running also?  The variable declarations could be in the UserForm code module, but what about the `Set` and lines below?  Are they executing in an event or somewhere else?

Comment: Lbl is defined in the userform module. The second code snippet is in the userform module also. I forgot to say that pTextBoxes is a collection. As I mentioned this all works perfectly with comboboxes, with code running in the same userform module, which is why I don't understand why there's a problem with textboxes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to say without seeing a more complete picture of the code.  `Type mismatch` should be easily debugged by adding a breakpoint and seeing what type you are dealing with.  I assume that `lbl` is declared `as TextBox` so that the type matches `TBox`?  Ultimately `lbl` is not what you think it is or you've got a variable defined incorrectly up above.  Debugging will tell you the former.  If it's the exact same code, hopefully you changed all the `ComboBox` references to `TextBox`... that would definitely be a type mismatch.

Comment: @Byron Thanks, as requested I have edited my question to include the full userform module in question, and both of my custom class modules. I did try declaring a new variable As Textbox, and using that to generate the textbox in case 7 and on the line that throws up the type mismatch, but that still resulted in a type mismatch, which is really confusing and infuriating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick testing, I am able to reproduce your error if I declare `TBox as TextBox`.  I do not get an error if I declare `TBox as MSForms.TextBox`.  I would recommend declaring all your `TextBox` variables with the `MSForms` qualifier.

**Test code** is situated similar to yours.  I have a `MultiPage` with a `Frame` where I am adding a `Control`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls("Frame1")

    Dim lbl As Control
    Set lbl = obj.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txt", True)

    If TypeOf lbl Is TextBox Then
        Debug.Print "textbox found1" 'does not execute
    End If

    If TypeOf lbl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        Debug.Print "textbox found2"

        Dim txt1 As MSForms.TextBox
        Set txt1 = lbl 'no error
    End If

    If TypeOf lbl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        Debug.Print "textbox found3"

        Dim txt As TextBox
        Set txt = lbl 'throws an error
    End If

End Sub
```

I am not sure why the qualifier is needed for `TextBox` and not `ComboBox`.  As you can see above, a good test for this is the `If TypeOf ... Is ... Then` to test which objects are which types.  I included the first block to show that `lbl` is not a "bare" `TextBox`, but, again, I have no idea why that is.  Maybe there is another type of `TextBox` out there that overrides the default declaration?

Comment: Fabulous, with that change it also works for me too. I have found that VBA is full of little idiosyncrasies (or are they just bugs :)) like this. For example I resize a listbox in my code, and I couldn't work out why the Width setting was being ignored (no error thrown, just didn't do anything, yet .Top, .Height etc all worked as expected. So I moved that line to the UserForm Initialize sub and it works, although that workaround may not always be practical. Anyway, thank you again for taking the time help me out with this and it's good learning in that it's always worth trying another method!

Comment: If this solves the problem, marking it as an answer (check mark under the voting buttons) helps others know so.

Comment: I agree that VBA can be a bit of a mess.  It allows a lot of flexibility to declare variables, late bind objects, implicitly convert types which can be abused.  It also works on top of Excel which makes the interactions two fold: is this a VBA problem or an Excel problem or something in the intersection?  The number of one-off "gotchas" (like this one) seem to add up and really drag the language down.  Unfortunately, there is also a lot of stuff that appears as a "gotcha" but makes sense once you know about it.  Knowing which is which is the real difficulty.